# Form becomes read-only with one additional join

Tags: ms-access, join

In [this picture](http://i.imgur.com/9zHzgR0.png), when I join LaborerID10 to ID in the Laborers table, my form that uses it suddenly becomes read-only. But if I delete the join on LaborerID11, it goes back to being editable. Is there some maximum number of joins I can use in a query before it making a form read-only? Would creating a different query that references this query circumvent this problem?

Thank you!

Edit: I did not find a solution to this, but I did realize that I did not need to do all those joins. For my purposes, I only needed one join for each table used. So I simply removed all of the joins except for LaborerID1 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your query uses a join over multiple tables and joins the tables on columns which are not primary keys. This makes a read-only query.

Here some detailed informations about that topic:

http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html

> Would creating a different query that references this query circumvent
>   this problem?

No, because a query that uses a read-only query will also be a read-only query.

The linked article also lists alternatives for your problem so you can pick the best solution.

Comment: If that is the case, why does the query in the image NOT make the form read-only, but adding just one more join that is structurally similar to many of the other joins does?

Comment: I cannot comment on that. What other queries?